# how to set default value to Html.dropdownlist using a local variable

Tags: javascript, html-select, default-value

I have a string `UserLevel` and I want to set the dropdown list value to the item that matches this string.
I have tried this:

```
$("#Level option:selected").val(UserLevel);
```

But it didn't work.

and I don't know how to use this:

```
$("#Level option[value='']").attr("selected", "selected");
```

Is there any other way?

Comment: is your UserLevel a variable or is that the string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just do this :

```
$("#Level").val(UserLevel);  //here 'Level' is dropdown 'id'
```

and if `'UserLevel'` is a `string` then there could be white space problem also then do as :

```
$("#Level").val($.trim(UserLevel));  //Use $.trim() here to remove white spaces.
```

and make sure values inside dropdown are also trimmed.

Above code will work here is fiddle code provided by @HowieH

Link :-http://jsfiddle.net/hhalse/s4qwaLgd/

Comment: just see there is any value inside dropdown same as UserLevel??..@Mary

Comment: I did! It works when I use a direct string, $("#Level").val("text");. but not with the variable.

Comment: Normally what @Exception is suggesting should work, see [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hhalse/s4qwaLgd/) . Could you provide us with some more details?

Comment: Yepp!! tanx a lot! @Exception

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this.

```
var text = "UserLevel";
$("#Level option:contains(" + text + ")").attr('selected', 'selected');
```

or iterate each value then compare.

```
   $("#Level option").each(function() {
  if($(this).text() == text) {
    $(this).attr('selected', 'selected');            
  }                        
  });
```

or you can use val to set the value directly. Here's [how](http://www.mkyong.com/jquery/how-to-set-a-dropdown-box-value-in-jquery/).